# Coping R function

Tags: r

For my own needs I would like to modify the following function:

```
plot.acf
```

from `stats` package.

I tried the following:

```
capture.output(getAnywhere(plot.acf), file = 'function.txt')
```

But when I try to execute/compile (not sure what is the right word here), I get the following errors:

```
Error in nr : object 'nr' not found
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Could anybody help me to understand these errors?

Comment: You might be interested in help("dput").

Comment: If you look at the output for `getAnywhere` you can see there is some non-code at the top. A better way to export that would be `dump("plot.acf","function.txt", envir=asNamespace("stats"))`

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you, your approach worked. Also I was very careful not to copy anything extra from `getAnythere`

Answer (score 1):

The problem in `function.txt` occurs about 20 lines down.

```
### Code above
with.ci.ma <- with.ci && ci.type == "ma" && x$type == "correlation"
if (with.ci.ma && x$lag[1L, 1L, 1L] != 0L) {
     warning("can use ci.type=\\"ma\\" only if first lag is 0")
    with.ci.ma <- FALSE
}
### More code
```

If you comment out the warning message (i.e.  `warning("can use ci.type=\\"ma\\" only if first lag is 0")`), everything is okay.